# Create new variable that can change along the document

Tags: variable

Apologies for the vague title, I do not know how to word this question properly.

I want to create a variable that keeps track of the date on which I finished a certain section of my course notes while lecturing in class. The variable should be allowed to change multiple times in the same document, so I cannot use `\newcommand` or the like, because I want it to appear in the TOC and the header of each page according to when the content was covered.

I don't even have an idea of how to start. Here is some presudocode:

```
...

\newvariable{\datestamp} % This is the command I'm looking for.

\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{\small{\datestamp}} % Variable is printed at the center of the header.

...

\begin{document}

\set{\datestamp}{Jan. 20} % From now until the next call of \datestamp the header will display "Jan. 20".
\section[Title of section 1 (current \datestamp - last \datestamp before following lecture)]{Title of section 1} 
% The title of the section appears in the document without the variable but shows up with the variable in the TOC.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Curabitur est lectus, viverra nec felis at, tincidunt tincidunt tortor. 
Mauris quis bibendum metus. Curabitur nulla arcu, tempus sit amet ultricies id, sodales non sapien. 
Ut turpis nisi, tincidunt at viverra non, tincidunt a dolor. 
In et urna elementum, elementum metus nec, dapibus ex. 
Aenean ultrices arcu vitae felis vehicula, laoreet vestibulum mi iaculis. 
Mauris nec ultricies neque, quis dapibus mi. 
Quisque pharetra purus non lectus mollis, sit amet tempor tellus mattis. 
Nunc porttitor porta nunc, non maximus lorem fringilla vitae. 
Cras neque augue, interdum quis neque at, tristique pretium quam. Vivamus convallis venenatis accumsan.

\set{\datestamp}{Jan. 22} % Lecture is over, but the section is not. Header displays "Jan. 22".

Cras quis dapibus sem. Maecenas at mollis nisl, ac aliquet massa. 
Maecenas eu erat libero. Nunc pharetra rhoncus augue, sit amet venenatis justo finibus nec. 
Praesent ac velit ipsum. Proin aliquam mauris sit amet interdum feugiat. 
Suspendisse gravida, lacus ut gravida pharetra, enim dolor tincidunt justo, vitae suscipit massa justo ac diam.

\section[Title of section 2 (current \datestamp - last \datestamp before following lecture)]{Title of section 2}

Cras mollis, risus id congue varius, quam quam luctus dui, et posuere neque magna et magna. 
In nec tortor est. Ut ut diam rutrum, feugiat elit sed, bibendum arcu. ...

\end{document}
```

In the TOC we would see:

```
1. Title of section 1 (Jan. 20 - Jan. 22) 
2. Title of section 2 (Jan. 22 - ... )
3. ...
```

For now I'd just be happy to figure out how to get this `\datestamp` to work.

Comment: You should probably use \edef or \xdef for a macro which changes frequently and is going to be written to the aux file.  See also \markright and \markboth for headers, although they are mostly used to only allow one change per page.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to use \def to make it work: `\newcommand{\stopdate}[1]{\def\datestamp{#1}}` does the trick without calling `\set`.

Comment: `\newcomand` and `\def` are almost the same thing.  Both do not expand the definition until used, so if you change the definition, `\write` (as opposed to `\immediate\write`) use the new version.